# How do I achieve this scenario?

Tags: selenium, testng

[image]

I have a project where I'm using selenium grid, Selenium, testng, and I'm stuck in this scenario: I want to run all test simultaneously in different nodes which are in different machines, my codes runs this test buy on either of the nodes.

```
<suite name ="Default suite" thread-count="4" parallel="tests">
    <test name="LOGIN TEST">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
    <parameter name="url" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"/>
    <parameter name="version" value="1.2"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.loginTest.LoginTest">
      //i have 4  test methods here
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="LOGIN TEST">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
    <parameter name="url" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"/>
    <parameter name="version" value="1.3"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.loginTest.MainPageTest">
      //i have 4 test methods here
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

---

```
@BeforeMethod
@Parameters( {"browserName","url","version"})
static WebDriver createInstance(String browserName, String url,String version) throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = null;
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("chrome")) {
            DesiredCapabilities  cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
    cap.setVersion(version)
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
            return driver;
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a json file like the one below .

```
  {
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "maxInstances": 2,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "maxSession": 2
    }
}
```

Use it while registering nodes with hub machine.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodev2.json -port 5556
```

Change the maxSession and maxInstance count according to your requirements.